# What visualizations do people use to debug a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, diagnostic

Imaging I am refining a model. What visualization can I rely on to help me identify an error, e.g. feature deficiency, data bias? A few graphs I am aware of include:
confusion matrix,
ROC,
learning curve. Anything else? Or is there a visualization tool/framework developed for such purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There are some videos at http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/~dicook/EDA.and.datamining/
and also on my vimeo site, eg https://vimeo.com/127615225 which illustrate approaches that I have used.

Comment: Those visualizations look cool! Is there any place where I find more information about those visualizations? Are there papers about them?

Comment: There is a paper coming out in the Statistical Analysis and Data Mining soon, titled "Removing the Blindfold" first authored by Hadley Wickham. Then look at the  www.ggobi.org and the Cook and Swayne book, that is linked from the publications.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you have done, and you want to sell ! Plotting the noise in regression, doing PCA before/after spiting your train/test data, are essential ones for example. One can plot the ROC, or plot the stability of models ... if you describe your case, the model and what you have done so far, me and others might come with smarter lists to enrich this discussion.